# Listview bound with Cursor adapter - how to add default first entry

Tags: android, listview, cursor, adapter

What is the common way to add a first default item to the listview, which takes it's data from a CursorAdapter? I would like to have a listview with items where the first entry is something like "Add item". 
Making a custom adapter won't help because it would mess up the cursor item count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situations the best solution is using the method [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29).

Why do u want taking data from cursorAdapter for the first item? Just set a TextView as a header view.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was searching for. I am not taking data for the first item, because it's just an dummy item to hold a "Add item" button. Similar like in the Messages application in HTC Sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a select with union

like

```
select 'Select something' as denominazione, 0 as _id union select denominazione, id as _id from ditta order by id asc
```